# How to display Error message into chart in asp chart controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspchart

I have a chart where I have to display message as "No Data Present",when rows.count == 0
else the bar chart as usually.

May i know how to display that message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I used if condition like this...

Comment: if (myTbl.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                Chart1.??? = "No Data Present in this Period";
            }
            else
            {
                //my chart

Comment: You can display the message in `Label` or `div`, why would you want it in the chart ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw text onto an empty MS Chart ChartArea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702430/how-to-draw-text-onto-an-empty-ms-chart-chartarea)

Comment: @V4Vendetta If I use label some users have records some not....that's why i want to display in charts

Comment: @Dev thanks a lot.The link is so helpful

Comment: @Chow.Net please accept and up vote my answer, it will raise my reputation and inspire me to help others for such problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
protected void ChartExample_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If there is no data in the series, show a text annotation
    if(ChartExample.Series[0].Points.Count == 0)
    {
        System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.TextAnnotation annotation = 
            new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.TextAnnotation();
        annotation.Text = "No data for this period";
        annotation.X = 5;
        annotation.Y = 5;
        annotation.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12);
        annotation.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        ChartExample.Annotations.Add(annotation);
    }
}
```

Thanks